# How to ask Google to update search content on same site URL

Tags: database, wordpress, joomla

I had a Joomla website and now I want to completely change it into WordPress.(cleaning the website and design a new website on that same URL)
But I have one question, as the website is working, many pages are indexed in google now how can I tell google that my website URLs has changed and doesn't show the broken old Joomla?

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect old URLs to new Wordpress.

so i recommend you to use this plugin (1+ million active installations)

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/
```

Once it's installed, just copy your joomla urls inside and make the right redirection.